# Display volume of a song as something that looks like a volume bar

Tags: python

I've created something that looks like a volume bar that changes based on how high the user has the volume.

Here I've set it to 63 as a example but it actually gets it from the Spotify API.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
volume_percent = 63

if volume_percent == 0:
    volume_graphic = '--------'
elif volume_percent in range(0, 12):
    volume_graphic = '=-------'
elif volume_percent in range(13, 25):
    volume_graphic = '==------'
elif volume_percent in range(26, 37):
    volume_graphic = '===-----'
elif volume_percent in range(38, 50):
    volume_graphic = '====----'
elif volume_percent in range(51, 62):
    volume_graphic = '=====---'
elif volume_percent in range(63, 75):
    volume_graphic = '======--'
elif volume_percent in range(76, 87):
    volume_graphic = '=======-'
else:
    volume_graphic = '========'

print(f'|Volume:{volume_graphic}|')
```

Comment: This looks like it is part of a larger program, if you want a code review post the entire program.

Comment: Note that there are some gaps between your sequences, for example `range(0, 12)`: 0-11 and `range(13, 25)`: 13-24. What happens when `volume_percent = 62`? I don't think this is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

### Unexpected Behaviour

As was already pointed out in the comments, your code does not work as intended for the edge cases of the ranges. Because the builtin `range` function treats the start as inclusive and the end as exclusive all the upper bound values are not checked and fall through to the `else` case.

For example setting `volume_percent = 12` results in the following output:

```
|Volume:========|
```

To fix this, the ranges have to be adjusted in the following way:

```
    [...]
elif volume_percent in range(0, 13):
    [...]
elif volume_percent in range(13, 26):
    [...]
elif volume_percent in range(26, 37):
```

### More elegant solution

For a more elegant solution you can use the string multiplication feature in python. For example `3 * '='` results in the string `===`.

Additionally you need a formula to calculate the required number of equal signs. This can be achieved by dividing the volume by 13 and then rounding up to the next integer. This rounding is provided by the `ceil` function in the `math` module.

It is probably also a good idea to create a function to generate the volume graphic.

This results in the following code:

```
from math import ceil

def create_volume_graphic(volume_percent):
    n = ceil(volume_percent / 13)
    return n * '=' + (8 - n) * '-'

volume_percent = 63
print(f'|Volume:{create_volume_graphic(volume_percent)}|')
```

### Further improvement

There are (at least) two problems with the above solution regarding coding style/readability/maintainability:

- the meaning of the magic numbers `8` and `13` are not inherently clear
- there is no error handling

The magic numbers can be made more explicit by using a variable to store the values. E.g. `length = 8`. What is in my opinion an even better solution is to make it an argument to the function with a default value.

Errors can occur if the function is called with negative numbers or numbers greater than 100. This can be checked at runtime and an exception describing the problem can be raised. Another type of error is providing an argument of an incorrect datatype (e.g. `create_volume_graphic("15")`). This kind of error can be addressed using type annotations. Type annotations serve as documentation for developers and can also be statically checked by tools such as mypy.

Finally it is also a good idea to include a docstring for the function.

```
from math import ceil

def create_volume_graphic(volume_percent: int, length: int = 8) -> str:
    '''Create ASCII art volume bar.

    Args:
        volume_percent: the current volume in percent, has to be in interval [0, 100]
        length: length of the resulting ascii art

    Returns:
        ASCII art string of length `length`

    Raises:
        ValueError if `volume_percent` is less than zero or greater than 100.
    '''
    minimum = 0
    maximum = 100
    
    if minimum <= volume_percent <= maximum:
        n = ceil(volume_percent / (maximum / length))
        return n * '=' + (length - n) * '-'

    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid volume: {volume_percent}, allowed range is {minimum} to {maximum}')

volume_percent = 63
print(f'|Volume:{create_volume_graphic(volume_percent)}|')
```

Comment: Another way to generate the volume string is to use `return (n * '=').ljust(length, '-')`